# CSS help to customize footer widgets

Tags: css, widget, footer

I am quite a beginner at webdesign and I need some help with my webpage. I use wordpress / generate press template. On the desktop mode the 4 widgets in the footer are in a single line, but when I switch to tablet or mobile they are on top of each other. I already managed to change the font size of the text in the footer, but I still can't get the widgets in a single line for tablet and mobile. Can you please help me? Please try to explain in the simplest of terms as I am not that good yet :D Thank you!

Comment: Without looking at code it's impossible to 100% know, but this sounds like a responsive CSS issue. If you're using Bootstrap or a similar UI framework/library that's probably a part of it. It is generally possible to create CSS selectors with a higher specificity score to override the defaults, but there could be a media query ruining that workaround. Some Google-friendly phrases: CSS specificity, responsive CSS, CSS media query.

Comment: Why would you want them in a line? They move like that so it is better for users to be able to see them without squinting or horizontally scrolling on the page.

If you really want to move them into a line, we will need your theme name, as everyone is different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I finally managed to find a way using the good old F12 command in the browser while checking my webpage. This command has helped me along the way with most issues I have had.

I used this code:

```
.inside-footer-widgets {
        display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;}
```

Although I am not quite satisfied as the last, 4th widget's text does not align the content to the center.

On a tablet I found the look of the page untidy with all the widgets under each other, now it's better. For the mobile view I kept the stacking version.
Here is my website [www.steelspiritdesigns.com](http://www.steelspiritdesigns.com)